# How to apply javascript alert before redirecting to next page on button click in asp.net

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I have a login page which redirects to admin home page i.e "frmAdminHomePage.aspx". This page is linked with masterpage "Admin.master". This both files are in same folder called "Admin". My question when i click button the following code does show error . The resource cannot be found. , Requested URL: /Visitors/Admin/frmAdminHome.aspx

Code is as follow

```
 protected void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('Alert worked succesfully');window.location ='~/Admin/frmAdminHome.aspx';", true);
}
```

Error as it gives in browser.
The resource cannot be found. , Requested URL: /Visitors/Admin/frmAdminHome.aspx

Comment: Try `window.location ='../Admin/frmAdminHome.aspx'` or `window.location ='./Admin/frmAdminHome.aspx'`. I assume the actual link for your Admin area is not under current path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `window.location ='../Admin/frmAdminHome.aspx'` or `window.location ='./Admin/frmAdminHome.aspx'`. I assume the actual link for your Admin area is not under current path.